# > Cabal install. "Error reading local package" when not on the company network (Win 10)

Tags: cabal, haskell-platform

Problem with cabal install

- When my Windows 10 machine is connected to the company network, it
  works Ok.
- When it's disconnected, It is not OK.

Log extract (computer **not** connected to the network)

> ...
>
> Cannot find curl on the path
>
> Searching for powershell in path.
>
> Found powershell at C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
>
> Searching for wget in path.
>
> Cannot find wget on the path
>
> Selected http transport implementation: powershell
>
> CallStack (from HasCallStack):
>
> die', called at .\Distribution\Client\Utils.hs:338:19 in main:Distribution.Client.Utils
>
> cabal: **Error reading local package.**
>
> Couldn't find .cabal file in: .

Log extract (computer connected to the network)

> ...
>
> Cannot find curl on the path
>
> Searching for powershell in path.
>
> Found powershell at C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
>
> Searching for wget in path.
>
> Cannot find wget on the path
>
> Selected http transport implementation: powershell
>
> Resolving dependencies...
>
> targets: C, base-orphans, blaze-builder, bytestring-builder, clock, old-locale, readable, stm
>
> ...

Of course, the .cabal file is in the current directory.

I did the installation of the Haskell Platform (8.4.3) with the computer connected to the company network.

How could I further debug the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I found was

With the computer connected to the company network:

1. remove the Haskell Platform
2. delete everything related (dir, $PATH$)

Disconnect from the company network

1. Re-install Haskell Platform
2. >cabal install: OK!